# How to return a delivery status to sns with a lambda subscriber

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am writing a lambda subscriber to an sns topic. The subscriber calls an http webhook and gets status code (200 if successful). How do I return a delivery status back to sns so it knows to retry?

Comment: You may want to put another notification in SNS so that the subscriber will pick that up to retry.

Comment: So you are saying this lambda needs to be a subscriber and publisher? I know there is a way to return a delivery status, I just don't know the format

Comment: Oh it seems like I should just timeout